# High charts (in Spago BI) - How to allow duplicates?

Tags: highcharts, spagobi

How can I allow my Chart to enter duplicate data?

Here is the data set
[image]

Here is the resulting chart
[image]

Here is my template. What is missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- see highcharts' documentation to view all possible options (http://www.highcharts.com/ref) -->

 <!-- div properties -->
<HIGHCHART  width='100%' height='100%'>

  <!-- chart object properties -->
  <CHART zoomType='xy' />

  <!-- title object properties --> 
  <TITLE text='Blabla'> 
  </TITLE>

  <!-- subtitle object properties --> 
  <SUBTITLE text='Source: qweqwe'> 
  </SUBTITLE>

  <!-- xAxis object properties  -->
   <X_AXIS showEmpty='true' categories="['00:00-00:59', '01:00-01:59', '02:00-02:59', '03:00-03:59', '04:00-04:59', '05:00-05:59', '06:00-06:59', '07:00-07:59', '08:00-08:59', '09:00-09:59', '10:00-10:59', 
    '11:00-11:59','12:00-12:59','13:00-13:59','14:00-14:59','15:00-15:59','16:00-16:59','17:00-17:59',
    '18:00-18:59','19:00-19:59','20:00-20:59','21:00-21:59','22:00-22:59','23:00-23:59']">
        <LABELS>
            <STYLE  color='#89A54E' />
        </LABELS>
        <TITLE text='Time'>
          <STYLE  color='#89A54E' />
        </TITLE>

   </X_AXIS> 

  <!--<X_AXIS alias='D' title='Weight'/> -->

  <!-- yAxis object properties  -->
  <Y_AXIS_LIST>
    <Y_AXIS alias='A'>
        <LABELS>
            <STYLE  color='#89A54E' />
        </LABELS>
        <TITLE text='Transaction Count'>
          <STYLE  color='#89A54E' />
        </TITLE>
    </Y_AXIS>


  </Y_AXIS_LIST>

  <!-- tooltip object properties 
  <TOOLTIP  backgroundColor='#FCFFC5' crosshairs='true' enabled='true' shadow='true' >
    <STYLE color='#FF00FF' fontWeight='bold' fontSize='16px' padding='5px' />
  </TOOLTIP> -->

  <!-- legend object properties -->
    <LEGEND layout='vertical'
         align='left'
         verticalAlign='top'
         x='1200'
         y='80'
         floating='true'
         borderWidth='1'
         backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'
         shadow='true'/>

  <SERIES_LIST allowPointSelect='true'>
      <SERIES name='Transaction Count' color='#89A54E' type='column' alias='A' />
      <!--<SERIES name='Rainfall' color='#4572A7' type='column'  alias='A' />-->

  </SERIES_LIST>

</HIGHCHART>
```

I tried putting in some such as showempty but still no luck.

I am currently doing trial and error with the use of this

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis

Answer (score 0):

I place 0 -23 as B in my resultset then

```
  <SERIES name='Transaction Count' color='#89A54E' type='column' alias='B,A'
```